# display largest word in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the largest word (contains the most characters) in my array to be displayed. so far example if someone enters 'cat' and 'mouse' the following message will be displayed below the words 'mouse contains 5 characters'.
What's the simplest way to go about doing this. Also how come "Name: Empty" never gets displayed when nothing has been entered into the input field.

```js
var array = [];
var Return;


function begin() {
var character = "Display words:";
var i = array.length

if (character.trim() === "") {
character = "Name: Empty"

}


  document.getElementById('ErrorOutput').innerHTML = character
  while (i--) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = array[i] + "<br/>" + document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;
}
}

function addwords() {

  Return = document.getElementById('input').value;
  array.push(Return);
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id=input></input>
<button onclick="addwords()" class="button" type = "button">enter words</button><br><br>
<button onclick="begin()" class="button" type = "button">display words</button><br><br>
<p id="ErrorOutput"></p>
<p id="message"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Create a variable like `longestWord` equal to empty string. Then for each item in array check if length of this word `x` is bigger than length of `longestWord`, then `longestWord` now becomes equal to `x`. In the end, the answer is stored in `longestWord`. It is almost a ready written code, you only need to add JS syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To get the largest word in an array you can sort the array by elements length:

```js
var arr = ['asdfa', 'asd', 'asdfasfasdfasdfasdfas', 'sd'];

arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
console.log(arr[0])
```

Or faster using [@Yeldar Kurmangaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218692/yeldar-kurmangaliyev) comment:

```js
var arr = ['asdfa', 'asd', 'asdfasfasdfasdfasdfas', 'sd'],
    longestWord = {word: '', len: 0};

arr.forEach(w => {
  if (longestWord.len < w.length) {
    longestWord.text = w;
    longestWord.len = w.length;
  }
});

console.log(longestWord.text, longestWord.len);
```

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev get the point and improved the solution.. Thanks for the comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

`while (i--) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = array[i] + "<br/>" + document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;`

Here, with your loop, you print all the word.

You can easly find the longest element of your array with the reduce function :

```
var longest = array.reduce(function (p, n)  { 
    if (p.length >= n.length) return p;  
    else return n; 
});
```

and finally

`document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = longest;`

Answer (score 0):

Here I made you simple snippet of it working.
Function **getTheLongestWord** takes array with strings, and returns the longest word as a string.

```js
var anArray = ["word", "longerWord", "theLongestWordInKnonUniverse", "notThatLongWord"];

function getTheLongestWord(a) {
  var longest = 0;
  var longestIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var length = a[i].length;
    if (length > longest) {
      longest = length;
      longestIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return a[longestIndex];
}

document.getElementById("placeHolder").innerHTML = getTheLongestWord(anArray);
```

```html
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```